# Why make utility cannot find header file?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, include, xilinx

I have been working in Eclipse based IDE called Vitis (IDE from Xilinx).
I have an automatically generated software project containing three automatically
generated Makefiles. Organization of the project is following:

```
zynq_fsbl
-Makefile_level_01
-main.c
-zynq_fsbl_bsp
 -Makefile_level_02
 -ps7_cortexa9_0
  -code
  -include
   -Config.h
  -lib
  -libsrc
   -peripheral_01
    -src
     -driver_peripheral_01.c
     -driver_peripheral_01.h
     -Makefile_level_03_01
   -peripheral_02
    -src
     -driver_peripheral_02.c
     -driver_peripheral_02.h
     -Makefile_level_03_02
   - ... same pattern repeats for other perpherals
```

**Makefile_level_01 contains:**

```
# Auto Generated by Xilinx generate_app. Modify at your own risk

CC := arm-none-eabi-gcc
CC_FLAGS := -MMD -MP       -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard 
CFLAGS := 
LN_FLAGS :=  -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -Wl,-build-id=none -specs=Xilinx.spec  -lrsa -Wl,--start-group,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group -Wl,--start-group,-lxilffs,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group -Wl,--start-group,-lrsa,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group                                      -Wl,--gc-sections

c_SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
S_SOURCES := $(wildcard *.S)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard *.h)
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(c_SOURCES))
OBJS += $(patsubst %.S, %.o, $(S_SOURCES))
LSCRIPT := -Tlscript.ld

CURRENT_DIR = $(shell pwd)
DEPFILES := $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $(OBJS))
LIBS := zynq_fsbl_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/lib/libxil.a
EXEC := executable.elf

INCLUDEPATH := -Izynq_fsbl_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/include -I.
LIBPATH := -Lzynq_fsbl_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/lib -L./

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(LIBS) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LN_FLAGS) $(LIBPATH) $(LSCRIPT)

$(LIBS):
    $(MAKE) -C zynq_fsbl_bsp

%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDEPATH)

%.o:%.S
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDEPATH)

%.o:%.s
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDEPATH)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(EXEC) *.o

-include $(DEPFILES)
```

**Makefile_level_02 contains:**

```
# Makefile generated by Xilinx.

PROCESSOR = ps7_cortexa9_0
LIBRARIES = ${PROCESSOR}/lib/libxil.a
BSP_MAKEFILES := $(wildcard $(PROCESSOR)/libsrc/*/src/Makefile)
SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %/Makefile, %, $(BSP_MAKEFILES))

ifneq (,$(findstring win,$(RDI_PLATFORM)))
 SHELL = CMD
endif

all: libs
    @echo 'Finished building libraries'

include: $(addsuffix /make.include,$(SUBDIRS))

libs: $(addsuffix /make.libs,$(SUBDIRS))

clean: $(addsuffix /make.clean,$(SUBDIRS))

$(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil.a: $(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil_init.a
    cp -f $< $@

%/make.include: $(if $(wildcard $(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil_init.a),$(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil.a,)
    @echo "Running Make include in $(subst /make.include,,$@)"
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.include,,$@) -s include  "SHELL=$(SHELL)" "COMPILER=arm-none-eabi-gcc" "ASSEMBLER=arm-none-eabi-as" "ARCHIVER=arm-none-eabi-ar" "COMPILER_FLAGS=  -O2 -c" "EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -nostartfiles -g -Wall -Wextra"

%/make.libs: include
    @echo "Running Make libs in $(subst /make.libs,,$@)"
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.libs,,$@) -s libs  "SHELL=$(SHELL)" "COMPILER=arm-none-eabi-gcc" "ASSEMBLER=arm-none-eabi-as" "ARCHIVER=arm-none-eabi-ar" "COMPILER_FLAGS=  -O2 -c" "EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -nostartfiles -g -Wall -Wextra"

%/make.clean: 
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.clean,,$@) -s clean 
clean:
    rm -f ${PROCESSOR}/lib/libxil.a
```

**Makefile_level_03 for peripheral_01 contains:**

```
COMPILER=
ARCHIVER=
CP=cp
COMPILER_FLAGS=
EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=
LIB=libxil.a
LEVEL=0

RELEASEDIR=../../../lib
INCLUDEDIR=../../../include
INCLUDES=-I./. -I${INCLUDEDIR}

INCLUDEFILES=*.h
LIBSOURCES=*.c

OUTS = *.o

libs:
    echo "Compiling driver_peripheral_01 ..."
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBSOURCES)
    $(ARCHIVER) -r ${RELEASEDIR}/${LIB} ${OUTS}
    make clean

include:
    ${CP} $(INCLUDEFILES) $(INCLUDEDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf ${OUTS}
```

My problem is that I am not able to compile the `driver_peripheral_01.c` module due to the problem with
`Config.h` header file inclusion. The `"fatal error: Config.h: No such file or directory"` is being invoked despite the fact that I have copied the header file in question into the `include` subdirectory in project directory structure. Does anybody have any idea why the make cannot find the `Config.h` header file? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There's too much makefile here for us to spend time deciphering it all.  The first thing to check is, what is the compile command line that make is printing out?  Does it contain all the flags like `-I` etc. that you expect?  If not, examine your makefile rule for building object files and figure out why the flags are missing, and ask specifically about that question with details from your makefile just about that.  Or, are the headers you want in those directories?  If not, either add more directories or move the files.

Comment: @MadScientist, thank you for your reaction. I have found the printing "Compiling driver_peripheral_01 ...". Directly above it there is "Running Make libs in ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/driver_peripheral_01/src"

make -C ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/adc_ctrl_ip_v1_0/src -s libs  "SHELL=CMD" "COMPILER=arm-none-eabi-gcc" "ASSEMBLER=arm-none-eabi-a
s" "ARCHIVER=arm-none-eabi-ar" "COMPILER_FLAGS=  -O2 -c" "EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -no
startfiles -g -Wall -Wextra". This printing comes form the Makefile_level_02. Unfortunately I don´t see the -I option there.